# Differences using std::string in C++ Builder and VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++builder

since I can get hands on the new RAD Studio Xe4 I thought I'd give it a try.
Unfortunatly, I am not so experienced with C++ and therefore I was wondering why the Code that works perfectly fine in VC++ doesn't work at all in C++ Builder.
Most of the problems are converting different var-types.
For example :

```
std::string Test = " ";
GetFileAttributes(Test.c_str());
```

works in VC++ but in C++ Builder it won't compile, telling me "E2034 Cannot convert 'const char *' to 'wchar_t *'.
Am I missing something? What is the reason that doesn't work the same on all compilers the same?
Thanks

Comment: It does work the same. However in one environment the project is set up to use normal characters, and in the other (C++ Builder) it's set up to use wide-character strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Windows Unicode/ASCII hell.

The function

```
GetFileAttributes
```

is actually a macro defined to either `GetFileAttributesA` or `GetFileAttributesW` depending on if you have `_UNICODE` (or was it `UNICODE`, or both?) defined when you include the Windows headers. The `*A` variants take `char*` and related arguments, the `*W` functions take `wchar_t*` and related arguments.

I suggest calling only the wide `*W` variants directly in new code. This would mean switching to std::wstring for Windows only code and some well-thought out design choices for a cross-platform application.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Additionally, there is a setting in the project options what equals to _TCHAR. Checking "char" instead of "wchar_t" does the job as well, I guess

Comment: @Henry It's better to just avoid the macros and tchar entirely. The macros and tchar exist to make it easy to switch code between the two options. Instead you should just directly use the functions you want (and you should prefer wchar_t functions because due to Windows' lack of support for UTF-8 the char versions are strictly less functional. IMO utf8everywhere.org has sound recommendations for the right thing to do on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ Builder config is set to use UNICODE character set, which means that Win32 APIs are resolved to their wide character versions. Therefore you need to use wide char strings in your C++ code. If you would set your VS config to use UNICODE, you would get the same error.

You can try this:

```
// wstring = basic_string<wchar_t>
// _T macro ensures that the specified literal is a wide char literal
std::wstring Test = _T(" ");     
GetFileAttributes(Test.c_str()); // c_str now returns const wchar_t*, not const char*
```

See more details about _T/_TEXT macros here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/TCHAR_Mapping

Comment: The `TEXT()` and `_T()` macros are subject to the `UNICODE` define. If `UNICODE` is not defined then the macros map to `char` instead of `wchar_t`. Since `std::wstring` is strictly `wchar_t` only, the correct way to write the declaration is to use the `L` prefix to force a wide literal, eg: `std::wstring = L" "; GetFileAttributesW(Test.c_str());`. Otherwise, if you really want to use the macros then you have to use `std::basic_string` instead: `std::basic_string<TCHAR> Test = _T(" "); GetFileAttributes(Test.c_str());`, which is consistent with `GetFileAttributes()` own use of `TCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `_UNICODE` and/or `UNICODE` in Builder and not defined it in VC.

Most Windows APIs come in 2 flavours the ANSI flavour and the UNICODE flavour.

For, when you call `SetWindowText`, there really is no `SetWindowText` functions. Instead there are 2 different functions
- `SetWindowTextA` which takes an ANSI string
and
- `SetWindowTextW` which takes a UNICODE string.

If your program is compiled with /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE, `SetWindowText` maps to SetWindowTextW`which expects a`const wchar_t *`.

If your program is compiled without these macros defined, it maps to `SetWindowTextA` which takes a `const char *`.

The windows headers typically do something like this to make this happen.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define SetWindowText  SetWindowTextW
#else
#define SetWindowText  SetWindowTextA
#endif
```

Likewise, there are 2 `GetFileAttributes`.

```
DWORD WINAPI GetFileAttributesA(LPCSTR lpFileName);

DWORD WINAPI GetFileAttributesW(LPCWSTR lpFileName);
```

In VC, you haven't defined UNICODE/_UNICODE & hence you are able to pass `string::c_str()` which returns a `char *`.

In Builder, you probably have defined UNICODE/_UNICODE & it expects a `wchar_t *`.

You may not have done this UNICODE/_UNICODE thing explicitly - may be the IDE is doing it for you - so check the options in the IDE.

You have many ways of fixing this

- find the UNICODE/_UNICODE option in the IDE and disable it.

or

- use `std::w_string` - then `c_str()` will return a `wchar_t *`

or

- Call `GetFileAttributesA` directly instead of `GetFileAttributes` - you will need to do this for every other Windows API which comes with these 2 variants.